# Creating a tree in lisp

Tags: tree, lisp, common-lisp

I've been doing a lot of research on trees in lisp and i'm attempting to solve a uva problem (11695 flight planning (http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2742) for  reference). I've currently solved most of it but i'm a bit stumped at the first hurdle with changing the input into a tree.
Examples of the input would be in the form of

1 2

2 3

3 4

I've come across quite a lot on the internet about how to set up a tree but most of the time its with the numbers lending themselves to being in a tree rather than having this kind of format. I've also looked into graph theory but that's got me nowhere.

The only headway I've made in this aspect is that i would probably have each of the "paths" placed into their own lists and the basic observation that the first of each list is the parent and the second of each list would be their child (which may also become parent to another child)

If anyone has any recommendations on how i could approach this that would be great. I haven't found anything that I've been able to apply to this online so i thought i would look to finding what other people's thoughts were.

I'm relatively new to Lisp but i have a reasonably good understanding of how it works.

Comment: Since you technically did not ask any questions (or at least I see none), I imagine you're looking for the right questions. For the question "What data structure do I use to represent the flight graph?", I would recommend a sorted array of pairs and their swapped doubles, since you only write to graph once but then read/search a lot. A hash table with cities as keys could help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an array of `n` elements (the cities) initially all NIL and then for each pair `a`/`b` you just do

```
(push b (aref cities a))
(push a (aref cities b))
```

once all the definition is read the `k`-th element of the array will be the list of cities you can reach from city k with a direct flight.